# Multiple excel formulas

Tags: excel, if-statement

Ok, so I am first using the following formula to get my account string:

```
=IF(H20>=400,"8"&RIGHT(S20,4),S20)
```

This turns my account number from a 78899 into a 88899. Unfortunately that account doesn't exist. The 78899 is a default number that needs to be changed to a 88000 or a 88010 depending on the description in another column of excel. How do I maintain the original formula (because that formula works to change account numbers that already in a 78010 format that gets changed to a 88010 format. I need the first formula to also be connected with a secondary formula to look up key words in a field, i.e. pizza, or airline to then change the 88899 to a 88000 or 88010.

Comment: you may have to use a series of nested if statements to get what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a nest if with an and statement, if I understand correctly......something like:

```
=IF(AND(S20=78899,I20="pizza"),88000,IF(AND(S20=78899,I20="airline"),88010,IF(H20>=400,"8"&RIGHT(S20,4),S20)))
```

You did not specify where "pizza" or "airline" might be so I used I20, but you could change to fit your needs.

Comment: That's great! How would I update to look for key words in the a cell, i.e. the "pizza" in Pizza Hut or the word "airline" in American Airline.

Comment: =IF(AND(S20=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("pizza",I20)))),88000,IF(AND(S20=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("airline",I20)))),88010,IF(H20>=400,"8"&RIGHT(S20,4),S20)))

Comment: If this helped, could you please mark as answered?  Thanks

Comment: The second part of the logic is not pulling through...i.e NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("")

Comment: =IF(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Air",G21)))),88000,I‌​F(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Robin",G21)))),88010,I‌​F(H21>=400,"8"&RIGHT‌​(S21,4),S21)))

Comment: TRY =IF(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Air",G21)))),88000,IF(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("robin",G21)))),88010,I‌​‌​F(H21>=400,"8"&RIGHT‌​‌​(S21,4),S21)))

Comment: Don't bother.....it does not work.....which is strange.  It works in Excel, but if I copy into this website and then copy my post back into Excel, it does not work

Comment: I got it to work, would I just add more lines if I wanted to capture more key words, Would I have to do another NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH - for every key word?

Comment: Well, it's nested.  So you would basically be putting it in the middle.  The IF statement syntax is basically IF(condition, if True, if False).  I‌​‌​‌​F(H21>=400,"8"&RIGHT‌​‌​‌​(S21,4),S21) would always be the last argument (with a few extra closing parentheses at end....one for each additional if statement

Comment: So essentially:
    =IF(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Air",G21)))),88000,IF(AND(S21=78899,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("robin",G21)))),88010,IF("condition","if TRUE",I‌​‌​F(H21>=400,"8"&RIGHT‌​‌​(S21,4),S21))))

Comment: To try to clarify my own comments...Nested if statements mean that the "if false" criteria of every if statement except the last one is another if statement so.....

=if(cond1,ifTrue1,IF(cond2,ifTrue2,IF(cond3,ifTrue3,ifFalse)))

such that if cond1 is true, ifTrue1 is the answer, if cond2 is true, if True2 is the answer and so on......If none of the conditions are true, the formula resolved to ifFalse

Hope that makes more sense than my previous comment, but since it is a confusing topic, I am going to leave both in case either one helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do like a vlookup search for keywords, where I can just add to the vlookup table for specific keywords in my if statement?